# Probability of at least d sequences having at least e outcomes in common with dice

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations

I have run into a very interesting (and challenging, I think) probability problem at work.  Below I present a generic version of the problem.  The goal is to create a function that can return the probability given 5 inputs, so I'm hoping to find an analytical answer to this (as opposed to bootstrapping).  The problem boils down to this:

There are $\alpha$ sequences of $\beta$ rolls of a (fair) $\gamma$-sided die.  What is the probability of at least $\delta$ out of the $\alpha$ sequences have at least $\epsilon$ of the $\beta$ roll outcomes match in their same positions within the sequence?

By that last phrase, I mean that:

sequence 1: 121

sequence 2: 112

only match in the first position with the "1".

The matches do not have to be consecutive.  So:

sequence 1: 1234

sequence 2: 1324

have two matches in the first and fourth positions.

Also, the matches only count toward $\epsilon$ if they match in all of the $\delta$ matching sequences.  In other words:

Sequence 1: 1234

Sequence 2: 1243

Sequence 3: 1256

Sequence 4: 2156

Counts as either 2 matches (positions 1 and 2) in 3 sequences (first three), or 2 matches (positions 3 and 4) in 2 sequences (last two).

Is there a general solution to this in terms of $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$, $\delta$, and $\epsilon$?  I have been able to solve for some limited versions of the problem, but the two "at least" parts are throwing me for a loop.  The one thing I am confident in, is that the denominator of the solution is $\gamma^{\alpha  \beta}$ to cover all the possible permutations of the dice rolls.  But I'm not really sure how to handle the numerator.

Comment: Your example (122,112) appears to match in the first and third place, as both are twos in the third place.  Can you clarify? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks!  That was an error.  I have fixed it.